# What do I do if I Suspect a User of "Downvoting for Downvoting"?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

**Edit**

This is extremely frustrating. I'm not asking for an investigation, I'm asking for *policy*. Just read my question, I mention I'm asking about policy. I know I lose a point for downvoting, that's fine. I also know I was downvoted on two separate answers almost instantly after I donwvoted someone else.

These are just details for my question:

## What do I do if I Suspect a User of "Downvoting for Downvoting"?

Or

"What is the policy regarding this?"

Or if there is no policy

"What does meta think about this? Are they fine with potentially high quality users leaving early? Is there no need for more answerers at this time?"

Now please stop accusing me of things, it's immensely frustrating.

**Edit2**

As it may be relevant, here are the questions and answers in question (I couldn't resist the pun :p). Please also let me know if *I* have done anything wrong.

The question I answered and voted on another, and was subsequently downvoted on two answers: [Remove all characters after a specific set of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36676472/608311)

The unrelated question that I answered and was also downvoted on: [How do you eliminate spaces from a list? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36531318/6083111) (Disclaimer: I have since edited the answer, see @rene's answer for the original)

**Original**

Recently (moments ago), I downvoted a user because their answer didn't answer the question fully. I first commented, and their response was more-or-less "I'm not fixing that, they could just do this or that."  With that response I figured that's what the button is *for*, no use in arguing.

Well seconds/a minute later I was notified that I lost reputation. My answer on the same question had been downvoted, and one where my answer hadn't previously been voted on. I can't see who did it.  I'm usually very careful in making sure my answers are accurate, and I don't have many other answers that have ever received downvotes.

What's the policy here? Do I report the post I voted on? From a newbie's perspective, I just want my answers noticed and to help people. I shouldn't have to deal with another user who can't handle a vote on one of their own answers just because they didn't read the question carefully.

This has been demotivating because I was pretty proud of my answer (even though the asker is gone), and now it's the lowest score out of 3 for no reason. Also the "-1" makes me look uninformed, when I see nothing wrong with my answers.

Comment: Nobody's going to investigate 1 vote. You'll just have to shrug and move on. A whole slew of downvotes though and they'll likely get reverted.

Comment: Also I wasn't sure whether to tag support or discussion. So some guidance on that would be appreciated :).

Comment: @RobertLongson, two things. I was downvoted on **two** answers. Another point though, should I expect to be bullied by users who've been on the site for a long time? Personally, I think he should receive a temp ban for vote manipulation.

Comment: You can technically tag both, although I think [tag:discussion] would be a better tag

Comment: Whenever you downvote _any answer_ you lose 1 reputation and the author of the answer loses 2.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I lost reputation for 3 events.

Comment: @user161778 that's not clear in your question.  I'll edit it to make it more obvious that you suspect revenge downvoting

Comment: @user161778 you lose 2 reputation for just one of your posts being downvoted, so it's only 2 events.

Comment: @ryanyuyu thank you, I appreciate that :)

Comment: Hmya, you don't know.  SO was designed so you could never be sure.  In general, giving a user a good reason to scrutinize the quality of your own posts is never a very spiffy idea.  Voting is anonymous at SO, always take advantage of that.  If you prefer the more confrontational approach then you can have that too, not much point in complaining about it however.

Comment: Can we investigate the down votes on my posts first? I have more ... but serious now: It could be [that Tim lost his keys *again*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/158100) ...

Comment: @HansPassant, so is there no policy regarding this, and the consensus is "do whatever"? That doesn't seem reasonable to me.

Comment: Downvoting culture depends a lot on the user. Personally I avoid it (although I had my rabid, outraged with world, downvoting moments after a tiring days work, which I latter regretted it). Sometimes you want to have more participation in the community and reputation is important. But it can also clog your mind a bit. Patience will take you a long way.

Comment: @user161778 how would we regulate that? We can't ask people to write an essay everytime they vote, then have a committee review it, right? In the same sense, it could be the user downvotes because you downvoted him. It may be a coincidence. It may even be that the user you downvoted took the time to look at YOUR posts because your interaction made him curious, and he downvoted with a legitimate reason. Since it's impossible to know which one of these it is, the reaction you're getting there is very appropriate, I'd say.

Comment: @armatita, is that to say there is no policy regarding this, and if I displease the wrong user, there are potential consequences for relatively no reason at all?

Comment: If a user downvotes too many of your posts, that'll be reverted. For a relatively small amount of downvotes, there's nothing to do

Comment: Link the post in question, invoke the Meta effect, get votes, ???, profit.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, should I do that? That feels wrong to me, like I didn't earn the votes properly.

Comment: @Patrice can you make this an answer please?

Comment: @user161778 Honestly, it's up to you. In theory, you can link it here and people are still expected to judge the answer's content before voting. You might get a few "sympathy" votes, but I'd imagine overall it would still be judged on its content.

Comment: @user161778 I wouldn't do as ArtOfCode suggested- If it turns out there _is_ an issue with your answer, it could backfire and you could get downvoted more. (Meta Effect swings both ways, though, so if it's a glorious masterpiece of an answer that deserves to be framed...) Judge the risk vs reward as you will. (I'd follow your gut feeling here.)

Comment: @kendra, put simply if there's an issue with my answer I want to fix it.

Comment: @user161778 Downvoting has been widely debated in the past. It's a gray  area since it relies mostly on subjective opinion. In the past I had some downvotes because the my answer wasn't copy paste. Maybe the OP thought it was incomplete (and downvoted it), and I thought that telling him the command to correct the problem was enough. Apparently I was wrong. Sometimes unfair stuff happens (as I said I've been the malefactor myself) but it's important to take it as a learning experience.

Comment: Which is good! Hopefully, if there _is_ an issue, someone will point it out to you. Just giving you a fair warning that the Meta Effect is a wild and untamed beast- Invoking it could be amazing, or a nightmare.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, updated with relevant Qs.

Comment: Just adding this was a great experience, I learned and it is nice watching the votes on the answers provided (Lots of votes!). I feel the rules are pretty "wild west" feeling, so I hope the poor mods aren't overworked, but I really think I like the (lack of) policy on this issue. I hope to help contribute positively to this community in the future, thanks guys!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please note that in this answer I'm not responding to your specific case (because you can not easily verify who voted on your posts), and I didn't read the posts you link to before posting this answer, but I'm talking about the more general case.

---

When you're absolutely certain that you've found a flaw in an answer, and you feel the need to express that through both a comment *and* a downvote, you put yourself at risk. Especially if you have a "competing" answer (because come on, answers hardly ever are complementary) posted under the same question.

It's just as simple as that: some users are so pathetic that they refuse to see or admit they're wrong, and feel it as a direct attack to their "honor" or whatever that you dare criticize them, so they feel the need to retaliate.

Nothing you can do but mentally blacklist that user.

In the end, you should be comforted by the fact that your answer is out there and it's the correct one; the proper votes will accumulate over time.

Answer (score 20):

Looking at the two answers that got [down voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/158100) (-2 for you, -1 for the voter) I can see why a down vote could be legit.

I'll use this original revision as an example:

> This was very trivial, you need an if:
>
> ```
> val = []
>
> for c in f:
>     if c != ' ':
>         val.append(ord(c))
>
> val = [w - 5 if w > 20 else w for w in val]
> ```

You're disqualifying the OP in your first sentence. The rest of your post is feeding the fish fingers to the OP. To be helpful you'll need to teach the OP how to fish. If you explain why you choose this solution, offering an insight in your problem solving tactic, backed with references to documentation the answer would be worth up votes.

Some more of your answers are like that. Code dumps that solve the immediate problem of the OP but I doubt any future visitor will think: *Hey, that was a clever explanation, so that is how it works*. And you should post for the future, not for the OP.

**tl;dr** There is nothing wrong with the policies, down voting works as designed. Some of your posts need work. Luckily there are still some users that down vote posts, otherwise you would have never known there was an issue.

Comment: OP tagged me, and thanked me for the answer in a comment on his question. I tried to guage my answer based on the skills they demonstrated in their question. Should I always add in that little bit extra explaining "c is a character, this compares it with a differet character ,`" "`. It's hard to simplify what's basically a uint8 comparison, maybe the question should just be closed as it's too simple?

Comment: Feeding fish fingers doesn't feel fair to me, I gave him literally one line in under 1 minute of him asking IIRC. It was a trivial question, I wanted it to be clear to OP that they were making the problem too hard (at least one other answer did too).

Comment: @user161778 ideally, yes. Stack was never meant for the OP to get his solution (it is a byproduct... a nice one for sure, but still a byproduct of what we try to build). It was meant to be a long lasting repository of knowledge about programming. Ideally, question askers wouldn't even be on here, we'd just have the actual nuggets of insight. The framework chosen to expose these nuggets was Q&A, but most of our policies (editing, duplicate, what is and isn't on topic) are based around the fact that every Q&A pair should be for the future viewers of the post.

Comment: I only wanted to give an extra option that could explain the down votes, given that the other answers are busy explaining the abuse case.

Comment: @Patrice, thank you that helps. I think I find myself answering questions that are against the scope of the website just to gain a couple points to get out of the frustrating limitations of being a new user.

Comment: @rene I complain but I do appreciate your insight, thank you.

Comment: @user161778 Then might I suggest edits if you want to get a bit of points quickly? You can get up to 1000 points by doing small things in posts that add value to them. Oh and it isn't always easy to get those first thousands where you can get some real moderation rights around the site, but you can always write an answer that works for the OP, then take the next 15-20 to edit a bit more "meat" into it?

Comment: Did you mean *-2 for you -1 for the voter*? :p

Comment: @Patrice, I just want 200 points so I can at least comment on other SE websites without having to earn 50 points every single time :). Believe me though I've been trying. I like to go through all my answers that the SE app lets me see after reading meta sometimes and try to see if there's any way I can improve them. I also have the small issue of I'd rather answer Golang questions but they're not very common yet :p. Is there a location on the website to see my answers? Maybe I should suggest that for the app?

Comment: @rene, I attempted to solve the issues you outlined. So I can avoid making low quality answers, could you please confirm the issues are indeed fixed?

Comment: That is an improvement, yes @user161778

Answer (score 5):

For one or two votes, there's nothing you can do. The policy for this is basically just "ignore it and move on" - you lose a few reputation points, which is annoying, but the people who have the tools to look at this (the community management staff) are too busy to investigate just a few votes.

If it becomes more of a problem, and you get multiple downvotes per day, there's a script that runs every day at 0300 UTC, which reverses patterns of serial voting such as this.

If it's even more serious, and the script isn't catching most of it, flag one of *your* posts for moderator attention, and explain the situation and ask the moderators to investigate. Moderators have access to aggregate voting information that will allow them to identify any users who are consistently downvoting your posts, which is grounds for timed suspension.

Comment: And *more serious* is? I think the OP's case is just a meh but if they decide to flag a post I'm pretty sure it will be declined.

Comment: @rene Definitely a meh right now. More serious is when you're consistently getting towards or into the tens of downvotes per day, and the script isn't reversing [m]any of them.

Comment: @ArtOfCode if you're getting that amount of downvote, and they aren't being reverted, means that they are coming from different people/ips/account. Either you're being downvoted by a competent sock-pupeteer (who I assume have better things to do than downvote on stack), or your answers REALLY deserve the downvotes. Not saying it's impossible that this is malicious, just that flagging whenever you get downvoted might be too quick of a reaction

Comment: @Patrice that's not necessarily what it means. There are cases when a single account can dish out more downvotes than you'd think - I'm not *entirely* sure what they are, but they exist.

Comment: @Patrice there are rumors where a user systematically down voted a user just below the reversal threshold for weeks.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I am skeptic in regards to that.. never seen it happen personally. If it DOES happen somehow, then yeah, flagging would be the appropriate thing to do

Comment: @rene granted. but below the threshold isn't "tens of downvotes a day". So unless you got a couple of these at once...

Comment: I will try it on your account @Patrice ... If I'm suspended tomorrow we learned something ;)

Comment: @rene kinda set myself up for that one did I? :P